# Can a popup call javascript functions on its opener if the two windows are on different subdomains?

Tags: javascript, popup, subdomain

I think the title of my question pretty much sums it all up. I'm wondering if I'll be able to send data from a popup back to its opener if the popup is in the same base domain as its opener, but a different subdomain. I'm aware that it's possible to send data by rewriting the hash part of the url, even across domains, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.

Comment: Why don't you try it? I think **no**, you can't do that.

Comment: I like asking these little, stupid questions, because then when the next person searches SO for an answer, they'll find the information they're looking for, and won't have to conduct the experiment themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set document.domain = "toplevel.com"; on both DOM's you should be able to communicate.

Comment: even easier, do `document.domain = location.host.replace(/^.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/g,'$1');`